# Linking an External CSS Stylesheet in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm making my first shiny application and am having trouble linking an external css file.  I've seen a few references where people have explained how to do it and even showed example code, but I haven't had any luck.  Most of the example I've seen it working used the bootstrapPage, like this:

```
  shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$title('Example linked stylesheet'),
      tags$link(rel = 'stylesheet', type = 'text/css', href = 'assets/ace-shiny.css'),
    ))
```

I'm using fluidPage, and don't know if that's my problem. My attempt is below.  I've confirmed that my working directory is where I think it is, and contains the "Assets" folder which holds the css file. I know the `tags$head` bit is working, since if I uncomment the `tags$style` there, it gets applied.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
     tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="assets/styles.css")
     #tags$style(type='text/css', "body {background-color: black;}")
  ))
```

My CSS at this stage is simple (below), so I know it's not the problem.

```
body {background-color: red;}
```

Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks for reading.
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `.css` file in a subdirectroy called `www`

**NOTE**

As gruvn mentioned in the comments, you need to make your `href` just refer to the files, and not include the `www` path. That is, use `href='mycss.css'` and not `href='www/mycss.css'`

Comment: John Paul - Thank you!  Just adding some clarification since it wasn't intuitive for me.  I ended up adding a "www" folder within my app's folder, and put my css file in there.  Then my link had to be `href = 'styles.css'`, NOT `href = 'www/styles.css'`.  It was counter-intuitive for me to not provide the full path.

Comment: Glad to help - I will add that in to the answer.